# Script to get GET METHOD of HTTP REQUEST time in cycle

Tags: linux

I want to run a script/command which with some interval (5 seconds) will make http request to certain site and shows the time of this request. At the same time I would like to set timeout for such requests. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really a very vague question. There are lots of ways to do this, so some context would be nice. What language would you prefer to use to get the job done? Are you just querying 1 site, or do you need to check multiple URL's?

Anyway. Here is a quick bash 1 liner that will do (my interpretation) of what you asked

`while :; do sleep 5; curl -w "time_total: %{time_total}\n" www.google.com -o NUL -s --max-time 5; done`

This is an endless loop that will sleep for 5 seconds, then make a curl request to the website of your choice (with a timeout of 5s) and then print the total time it takes for that request

Output:

```
time_total: 0.094
```